# How can I debug my Django models to see what the properties contain?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created a model in a Django application. Let's say I have a model class `Car` in models.py. This class has a method called `refuel()` that interacts with the class' properties.

I want to write a Python script that imports models.py, instanciates the class and calls `refuel()` so to then debug the class using Breakpoints with my IDE.

However, for some reason, I cannot import the model file in another script. When I use this syntax to import the file:

```py
from .models import Car
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Note that the script I import the model in is located in the same folder as models.py.

What's the way of solving this problem, or, more broadly, what's the best way of debugging my model file ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file within your folder where your relevant `models.py` file is?

Comment: Yes, I do have this file.